# Open source NLP annotation tool/library supports active learning

Tags: nlp, dataset, annotation, active-learning

I am looking for an NLP annotation tool/library that supports active learning. I am looking for something that works in this scenario:

- Annotating N samples.
- Training a model on the annotated data.
- Getting the model's predictions on the next N unlabeled data.
- Correct/annotate (manually by the annotator) the annotations of the unlabeled data.
- Retrain the model by including the labeled data from the last step.

I found a library that's called Prodigy but it's not free. Any suggestion for a free library?

Answer (score 2):

For my projects I use [NLP Lab](https://www.johnsnowlabs.com/nlp-lab/), by John Snow Labs. It provides automated annotation and model training, saves time compared to other tools, and is completely free of charge. Another impressive thing about it (which I found) is that you don't need to have a prior experience in coding, because there is no coding involved. You can even invite your team members and collaborate with them in your project.

The documentation can be a long read, I have provided a direct link here: [docs](https://nlp.johnsnowlabs.com/docs/en/alab/quickstart)

Answer (score 1):

There is a tool **Acharya** which does this, available here (https://github.com/astutic/Acharya).

You can upload your dataset and then add any algo to train a custom model and use it for further annotations.

Their documentation regarding adding an algorithm is a bit confusing but adding it is pretty straight forward, to begin with you can simply copy paste a configuration template which they provide into the **Add algo** section, this config template which trains a **spacy ner** model and is available here:

https://github.com/astutic/acharya-spacy/blob/setup/algo_configuration.yaml